# How to switch from IDE to AHCI from outside the bios?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios, sata, ahci

I want to change my sata hard from ide to ahci. But in my advanced bios menu there is no option to do that three is no ide configuration or sata configuration.

I'm using laptop is there another way to do this outside the bios menu

Comment: what's the laptop model?

Answer (score 3):

Plain and simple: No.
The BIOS must support it.
If it doesn't you are out of luck.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer but i can't do that in my laptop because the advance option is looked is there any way to open it ? thanks for your help

Comment: Also some mainboards won't show an option for AHCI since it's somehow always activated (has been the case for an Asus one I used).

Answer (score 1):

Gigabyte released a new utility that allows you to change the mode of the chipset SATA controller between IDE, AHCI, and RAID (if available), from within Windows.

For now on, who have Gigabyte MB have this possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an admin password to your bios, reboot, enter bios and enter password.

It's weird, I know, but some bios works this way. You should be able to access some more sections.

If not, then do a bios upgrade. If it still doesn't have that option, then you are out of luck.